How to I convert matrix to another coordinate system?
I need to convert matrix's from a "Y-Up Right-Handed" coordinate system, to a "Z-up left handed" coordinate system.
I am, new to the concept of matrices, could anyone help me with this?
In the past, I only needed position data, so I would do the following in order to convert coordinate spaces:
FVector vertex_Corrected = FVector(vertex.X * -1, vertex.Z, vertex.Y * -1);
however now I need to access rotation data aswell, so it seems I no longer can use this simple method.
